# unable to inject dependency in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-webapi

Hi i am following microsoft docs ...

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider

in order to inject configurations as singleton in .NET Core Web API

Here is **Program.cs** code where i load my configurations:

```
public class Program
{
    public static Dictionary<string, string> arrayDict =
   new Dictionary<string, string>
   {
        {"connString", "Data Source =xxx/xxx;User Id =xxx;Password =xxx"}
   };
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
        {
            builder.AddInMemoryCollection(arrayDict);
            builder.AddJsonFile(
                "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: false);
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
}
```

Here in **Startup.cs** i use following

```
public class Startup
{
    private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

    public Startup(IConfiguration config)
    {
        Configuration = config;
    }


    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}
```

Still when i am using dependency injection in my Controller i am unable to inject IConfiguration, and get following error at invoking cotroller action (runtime error):

**A suitable constructor for type 'IrisDotNetCore.Controllers.LoginController' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.**

**LoginController.cs** Code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class LoginController : ControllerBase
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;


    LoginController(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```

What is possibly wrong here?

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why arre you trying to inject `IConfiguration` to begin with. That can be seen as a code smell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor has to be public or internal - remember that in your situation the instance of the LoginController can't be created (because `LoginController` method is private). Even the error message (Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a **public** constructor) suggests this.

Comment: Are you sure? `internal` is default for classes, not constructors or other methods (which are private by default). But you're right that `internal` is accepted next to the `public` (but must be explicitly set). I've added this information to the answer.

Comment: @Tearth thats correct my ctor was not marked public, also there was no need to add IConfiguration as singleton as its default behaviour of .net core to inject it